# Export several vectors to text files

Tags: r

I have 100 vectors, each containing random numbers.

> Vector1, vector2 vector3 vector4... vector1000

I want to write them out to several .txt files, to have 100 different txt with different names, each containing one vector.
I was trying with a for loop, but I failed when I was trying, thats what i have for so long:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  filename<-paste("textfile", i, ".txt", sep = "")
  writeLines(vector[i], filename)

}
```

**UPDATE:**
My vectors are integer, I created them like this:

```
x=1 
While (x < 101)   
{ 
  vectorx<- sample(1:5000,1000, replace = T)
  assign(paste("vector",x,sep=""),vectorx) 
  x=x+1 

}
```

Comment: From your code, it seems more like you have one vector which is 100-number long, rather than 100 vectors.

Can you do a `str(vector_name)` to confirm for us what is the structure of your variable?

Comment: In what did it fail?

Comment: Updated!
I failed because writing "vector[i]" after writelines, doesnt mean it will write out vector1 and then vector2 and then vector3 etc.

Comment: Your problem aside, I would strongly suggest using a matrix rather than creating 100 different variables.

Answer (score 2):

There might be better ways to do this, but with minimal modifications of your code you could try

```
for (i in 1:100) {
 filename <- paste0("textfile", i, ".txt")
 writeLines(as.character(get(paste0("vector",i))), filename)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# We have to use **get** for bringing the value out of the variable
for (i in 1:10) 
{
  filename<-paste("textfile", i, ".txt", sep = "")
  writeLines(get(paste("vector",i,sep="")), filename)
}
```

Comment: This one looks pretty much like the answer by @RHertel it also doesn't seem to loop through the vectors in the `paste()` call. It has `1` instead of `i`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it should be "i" instead of 1. Sorry. I have edited

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to your question but maybe a solution for your problem:

```
# create an empty list
x <- NULL

# fill it with the random samples you want to create
for( i in 1:100 ) x[[ i ]] <- sample( 1:5000, 1000, replace = TRUE )

# write each sample to a file
for( i in 1:100 ) cat( x[[ i ]], file = paste( "vector", i, ".txt", sep = "" ) )
```

Obviously, you could combine the last two steps, creating a sample and write it to a file right away:

```
for( i in 1:100 )
{
  x[[ i ]] <- sample( 1:5000, 1000, replace = TRUE )
  cat( x[[ i ]], file = paste( "vector", i, ".txt", sep = "" ) )
}
```

**Edit**: You don't need the list `x` for this:

```
for( i in 1:100 ) {
      # tmp is just a temporary variable overwritten in each iteration
      tmp <- sample( 1:5000, 1000, replace = TRUE )
      cat( tmp, file = paste( "vector", i, ".txt", sep = "" ) )
}
```

Comment: You don't need the temporary list `x`, a simple temporary variable `tmp` within the `for` loop is sufficient. I edited your answer accordingly.